# Android countdown timer keeps iterating between previous and current value

Tags: android, time, timer, countdowntimer

Hi I'm working on an app with a countdown timer. When the button is clicked the timer starts based on the user inputs into the text field,when I change the value of the text field and a new value for the timer starts, it flashes and shows the previous countdown value and counts both the values down,flashing between the previous and the current countdown value. How do I get the timer to forget the value from before and only use the current timer value.

I tried using the cancel function however that didn't work, I think it's something in my tick function however I'm not sure what it is.

Here is my code:

```
   CountDownTimer mcountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(getmonTime(), 1000) {          // adjust the milli seconds here

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    long hr1=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours( millisUntilFinished);
                    long sub1=hr1*60;
                    long min1=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
                    long sub2=min1*60;


                    timer.setText(""+String.format("%d hr,%d min, %d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours( millisUntilFinished),

                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)-sub1,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)-sub2,
                                    -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

                }


                public void onFinish() {

                    timer.setText("0");
                }



            };

                    mcountDownTimer.start();






        }


    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't cancel the previous one.

Save the instance of the `CountDownTimer mcountDownTimer` (BTW rename it to `mCountDownTimer`)
And before setting a new one, cancel the old one using:
`mCountDownTimer.cancel();`
and only then create the new instance. 
E.g:

```
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

@Override
public void onCreate...
...

if (mCountDownTimer != null) mCountDownTimer.cancel();
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer...
```